# gradient of inequality constraint with slack variable

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the following [problem](http://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/InteriorPointMethod)

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min && x_2(5 + x_1) \\
s.t. && x_1x_2 &\geq 5 \qquad & (c_1)\\
&& x_1^2 + x_2^2 &\leq 20 \qquad &(c_2)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

I introduce slack variables $s_1, s_2 \geq 0$ to transform the inequality constraints to equality constraints, and the problem becomes

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min && x_2(5 + x_1) \\
s.t. && -5 + x_1 x_2 - s_1 &= 0 \qquad & (e_1)\\
&& 20 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 - s_2 &= 0 \qquad & (e_2)\\
&& s_1, s_2 \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

How does introducing $s_1$ and $s_2$ to my original constraints change the KKT system? Is the gradient of my first constraint

1. $$
       \nabla_x e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ x_1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
       $$
2. $$
       \nabla_x e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ x_1 \end{bmatrix}
       $$

and if it's (2), how do I deal with the slack variables $s_1, s_2 \geq 0$?